# Unable to iterate over every item in the array of questions using promises in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, asynchronous, promise

I need to store the questions in an array and use the spread operator to create an array of promises and use Promise.all to wait on them and collect the answers in a different array. But my code is taking only first value and not going to the next question.

```
const rl = readline.createInterface(process.stdin, process.stdout);

function PromiseAllReadline(){
   const questions=['What is you NAme?','What is your Age?','What is your Occupation?'];
   const answers=[];
   const promiseQuestions=questions.map((question)=>{
       return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
           rl.question(question,(input)=>resolve(input));
       });
   });

   Promise.all(promiseQuestions)
     .then((values)=>{
         console.log('values',values);
     })
     .catch((error)=>{
         console.log('error is',error);
     });
}

PromiseAllReadline();
```

Comment: What does `rl.question` do? Can it be called many times before any answer is given?

Comment: @trincot [rl.question(query, callback)](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_rl_question_query_callback)

Comment: OK, but then I fail to see how `Promise.all` could be useful, since (in a correct implementation) you would never have more than one pending promise.

Comment: In this case I want to create an array of promises which wait for answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in the following code you call `rl.question` for *all* questions immediately, while you should wait with launching the second question until after you got the answer to the first, ...etc.

```
const promiseQuestions=questions.map((question)=>{
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        rl.question(question,(input)=>resolve(input));
    });
});
```

Make your function `async` and use `await` in a `for` loop to execute one question after receiving the answer to the previous. This results in *one* promise, so `Promise.all` is not useful here. `Promise.all` would be useful if you could execute the questions in parallel (which you tried), but `rl.question` does not work like that.

Here is the suggested solution. For it to run in a browser snippet, I mocked `rl` (ignore that code):

```js
// Mock for rl:
const rl = { question(question, callback) { document.querySelector("div").textContent = question; let input = document.querySelector("input");let button = document.querySelector("button");input.value = "";button.addEventListener("click", function handler() {button.removeEventListener("click", handler);callback(input.value);});}};

async function promiseAllReadline() {
    const questions = ['What is you Name?','What is your Age?','What is your Occupation?'];
    const answers = [];
    for (let q of questions) {
        answers.push(await new Promise(resolve => rl.question(q, resolve)));
    }
    return answers;
}

promiseAllReadline().then((values) => {
    console.log('values', values);
}).catch((error) => {
     console.log('error is', error);
});
```

```html
<div></div><input><button>Submit</button>
```

Comment: Not sure what you are on about. I never wrote that `Promise.all` was the main problem.